# Excel vloookup function not working as expected: flag creation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Sheet 1

```
   A         B    C       D       E       F            G           H          I
1  emp_id   Mgr SKL1    SKL2    SKL3    concatM1    Concatsk1   Concatsk2   Concatsk3
2   1         5  8       9       18         1_5       1_8         1_9         1_18
3   5         8  9       18                 5_8        5_9        5_18        5_
4   8         9  18                         8_9        8_18       8_          8_
5   9         18                            9_18        9_        9_          9_           
6   18                                      18_        18_        18_         18_
```

Just an example

Here empid 1 has empid 5 as manager, empid 8 is his skip level manager 1, empid 9 is his skip level 2 manager and empid 18 is his skip level 3 manager.(concats are just for formula etc, joining emp id with manager id, and skip level manager id)

Sheet 2: expected output (should give flag for any random emp manager combination whether manager employee relation exists or not and what type of relation exists)

```
   A        B            C           D       E       F
1 emp id   manager id  concat      Mgr  SKL1    SKL2     SKL3   
2  5          9         5_9        No    Manager  No      No
3  8          18        8_18       No    No      Manager  No
4  9          5         9_5        No    No      No       No
```

Code written in sheet 2 D2 cell to find out whether manager is direct manager for employee or not

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($C2,'Sheet1'!F:I,1,0),"Manager","Not correct"),"No")
```

Code written in sheet 2 E2 Cell to find out whether the manager is skip level 1 manager or not

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($C2,'Sheet1'!F:I,2,0),"Manager","Not correct"),"No")
```

Code returns No for everything, so there is something wrong with my codes

Comment: It's a lot easier to use `COUNTIFS` here.

Comment: how? I wish to create flag whther a person is manager or skip level manager or not manager at all. how will countif help? i just want output, whether i get output by vlookup, hlookup or countif anything is cool'

Comment: Your last `vlookup` parameter is `0`, do you mean `false` instead?

Comment: false and 0 are going to do the same thing in vlookup

Comment: True. The issue is a comma instead of an equals sign. I have posted an answer to illustrate.

Comment: No doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier with COUNTIFS:

Simplified example here on one sheet:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$H3,E:E,$I3)>0,"Manager","No")
```

[image]

Comment: same manager has multiple reportees. will this work for many to one or many to many type of relationships?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes tried . Giving wrong result. So one employee has one direct manager only , but one manager can have many employees under him.

Comment: You may want to edit your question with how you tried it.

Comment: what should i write...I have tried exact same way and getting 0 in all cells

Answer (score 0):

Here's why your original code was not working, and how to fix it.

## Problem

First `,` on if statement should be `=` instead.

## Solution

Change this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($C2,'Sheet1'!F:I,1,0),"Manager","Not correct"),"No")
```

To this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($C2,'Sheet1'!F:I,1,0)="Manager","Not correct"),"No")
```

This solution is for your first formula. You can change the second one too, for the same correction.

## Also

It looks like you have swapped around "Not correct" and "No" in your formula:

- Where you have "Not correct", this is the text that will return if the vlookup does not return "Manager" >> did you mean "No" instead?
- Where you have "No", this is the text that will return if the if statement evaluation returns an error (e.g. if the vlookup returns "#N/A") >> did you mean "Not correct" instead?